# Multiple conditions in the same guarded case statement in Scala?

Tags: scala

I have several conditions that I want to stack in a scala match statement. In another language I could just omit the 'break' between the cases of a switch statement.

I know I can combine raw alternatives separated by a pipe character, but can't seem to find how to combine guarded cases, e.g.:

```
val isAdmin = true
myval match {
  case 1 if isAdmin => ...
  case 2 if isAdmin => ...
  case 1 | 2 => // this is fine but doesn't apply the guard, so no use
  case 1 | 2 if isAdmin => // doesn't apply the guard to '1'
  case 1 if isAdmin | 2 if isAdmin => // invalid syntax
}
```

Is it possible to combine the first two cases somehow?

Comment: have you tried grouping using parentheses? (just a guess)

Comment: `case 1 | 2 if isAdmin =>` applies the guard to both cases. `1 match {case 1 | 2 if false => 1 case _ => 2}` returns `2`

Comment: I could have sworn that didn't work when I tried it...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The guard statement applies to everything, for good or for ill.  This means that your example

```
  case 1 | 2 if isAdmin => ...
```

actually does what you want and what you say it does not, but it also means that

```
Option("Hi") match {
  case Some(x) | None if x == "Hi" => 1
  case _ => 0
}
```

does not work.  (In fact, it doesn't even compile.)

Fortunately, Scala lets you drop a def in practically anywhere.

```
def caseNice = 1
Option("Hi") match {
  case Some(x) if x.length < 3 => caseNice
  case None => caseNice
  case _ => 0
}
```

which is how you should deal with common functionality that is difficult invoke from a single `case` statement.